# how to order a Localized text list

Tags: asp.net

I wonder if anyone can tell me or give me a guide of how can I order a objet List(Key,Name) by name, but name is in LocalizedText format and maybe I'm so stupid, but I can't order this List.

```
//Objects definied on my class:
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Guid ComplaintPreventableStateId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual LocalizedText Name { get; set; }


  //function that tries to get information:
 IList<ComplaintPreventableState> complaintPreventableList = new List<ComplaintPreventableState>();
        complaintPreventableList = (from c in ComplaintPreventableState.All select c).ToList();
   //Tried this two options:           
 complaintPreventableList.OrderByDescending(h => h.Name);
 complaintPreventableList.OrderBy(h => h.Name);
```

Comment: You should post some code; anything you have would help. I have put an answer in, though it's all based on assumptions.

Comment: Re-read my answer... Adding an update. Re-iterating what i said before; you aren't assigning the order back to itself. When you call OrderBy your just setting up a method that will be used when you call .tolist() on the list. If you want it to persist you need to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a list of `KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)` for this example, as you can't have a `List()` with 2 types- it would be the same if you were using a `List(Of Object)` too.

```
        // Your list object
        Dim list As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

        // putting some values in the list
        list.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(1, "Bob"))
        list.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(1, "John"))
        list.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(1, "Harry"))

        // Ordering your list by the Value
        list = list.OrderBy(Function(p) p.Value).ToList()
```

This sets the list with order by name, which becomes Bob, Harry, John.

**UPDATE**

So, using your code as an example you need to change this:

```
     complaintPreventableList.OrderBy(h => h.Name);
```

To this:

```
     complaintPreventableList = complaintPreventableList.OrderBy(h => h.Name).ToList();
```

Notice the call `.ToList()` at the end too.

As in my example earlier; you need to assign the ordered list back to itself

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't fix my problem I use OrderBy and OrderByDescending, but nothing changes on results order.

Comment: are you assigning your list back to itself - notice above `list = list.OrderBy(Function(p) p.Value).ToList()` - this is setting `list` to the new order. This is a 100% working way to do it. if it's not working, you have other issues and should post code

Comment: Finally a friend  give me this option:                                       
            IList<ComplaintPreventableState> complaintPreventableList = new List<ComplaintPreventableState>();
            complaintPreventableList.AddRange(ComplaintPreventableState.All.ToList().OrderBy(k => k.Name.ToString()));

Comment: It's no different. All your doing is the same thing - your adding an ordered list back to your original list

Comment: Infact the solution you mention there is not as fast as you are having to call 2 methods - `addrange` and `tolist` - with my solution you only call one `tolist`